# exploding memory usuing permutations from itertools

Tags: python, memory-management, permutation, python-itertools

I am using permutations from itertools to make a list of possible combinations of a list of sentence chunks but it seems to explode the memory even on my 64GB machine very quickly.  I am not the best when it comes to memory management so I would like to learn how I can make my code better. If I could compute a list of several thousand of these chunks, that would be great. Right now I can only really afford 10.

```
import itertools
from os import sys

arq_in = sys.argv[1]
f1 = open(arq_in, 'r')

list_items = []
items = []

lines = f1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line =line.strip()
    list_items.append(line)

for L in range(0, len(list_items)+1):
    for subset in itertools.permutations(list_items, L):
        items.append(subset)

output = "\n".join(" ".join(map(str,l)) for l in items)
print output
```

here is my input:

```
ah k l ih r ih ng hh w ae r
ah s eh k ih n d t w ih ch t
ah s iy k r ih t w ah r l d
ah s l iy p ih ng k ae p s l
ah v ay t ah m ah n ae n d
d aw n ih n b ih k ah r ih ng
d ey t ah p oy n t s ih n
ey jh ih n s iy hh ay ah r d ah
f ih ng g ah r hh ae d ah
ih g z ih s t ih n w ao r m
ih k s p r eh sh ih n ih n dh ah
ih n d ah l jh ih n ae n
ih n m ay ey jh ih n s iy
ih n v eh s t ih n b l ae k
ih z m eh zh ah r d ih n
m ae ch ih ng y aa r n ih n
r iy d ih ng ih n p uh r
s ah ch ah d ih z ae s t ah r
s ih s t ah m ae n d ae d
th r eh d m ae ch ih ng y aa r n
```

Comment: If you only need a few thousand, break out of your loop after you have enough.  The number of permutations will grow extremely fast.  For the number of inputs you have here it will easily outgrow your memory.  Also, your input contains duplicates, so you'll be creating the same permutation multiple times.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running it in the following way will make sure you won't run out of memory, since we're using lazy evaluation (meaning, we'll compute the next iteration only when we need it).

This approach has the advantage of *not* keeping the whole thing in-memory, so even though it will still run for a very long time until it finishes (it runs over an hour on my machine and still hasn't finished!) but it won't crash:

```
import itertools
from os import sys

def lazy_iter(lines):
    list_items = []
    for line in lines:
        line =line.strip()
        list_items.append(line)

    for L in range(0, len(list_items)+1):
        for subset in itertools.permutations(list_items, L):
            yield subset


if __name__ == "__main__":
    arq_in = sys.argv[1]
    f1 = open(arq_in, 'r')
    lines = f1.readlines()    
    for l in lazy_iter(lines):
        print map(str,l)
```

Assuming you don't really want to `print` any such `l` as a string, you can restrict the iterations to run only for the number of items you want to generate and do with each one of them whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

As @BrenBarn points out, there are many permutations for even relatively small lists. Indeed, for a list of *n items* from which you choose *i* items, there are *n! / ((i!)(i-1)!)* permutations. However, if you can afford the processing time (which you will have to, in order to fully process the list), instead of processing the entire set of permutations all at once, you can use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), as `itertools` does, to incrementally build up your final result.